# Circles with numbers

Tags: probability

[image]

This is a diagram Venn,what choice it discribes (AB)'UC

The choices are :

```
a)2,4,5
b)1,2,5
c)something else
d)1,3,4,5
e)1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: what is your experience with Venn diagrams? What do you think $(AB)'$ is?

Comment: What does $AB$ mean?  Do you mean $A\cap B$.  So are you asking what represents $(A\cap B)^c \cup C$?

Comment: i have answer c)something else...because the circle C is not with them

Comment: yes exactly @fleablood  . but (A∩B)c∪C  not c...(AB)′∪C

Comment: Your picture is, unfortunately, poorly drawn and not recoverable.  It looks like $A$ is a set with a single element in it: "1", and $B$ is a set with a single element in it: "3".  Then there seems to be a third unlabelled set with just "2" in it.  Then the sets are drawn as though the have areas of intersection but there are no elements in those intersections (so they should never have been drawn as such).  ... Unfortunately it is not possible to make sense of this.

Comment: Your picture is, unfortunately, poorly drawn and not recoverable. It looks like A is a set with a single element in it: "1", and B is a set with a single element in it: "3" exactly as you wrote it. The "2" is between A and B.The C circle that has "4" is far away from other circles

Comment: I use the lower case and super scripted $^c$ to mean the complement of a set.  So $A^c = \{x| x\not \in A\}$.  It doesn't have anything to do with the set $C$.  We can use the notation $A' = \{x| x\not \in A\}$ if you prefer.  Does "(AB)'UC" mean $(A\cap B)' \cup C$?  In other words $(A\cap B)' \cup C= \{x| x\in (A\cap B)'$ or $x\in C\} = \{x|x\not \in (A\cap B)$ or $x \in C\} = \{x|$ it is not true that $x$ is in both $A$ and $B$, or it is true $x \in C\}$

Comment: mean (A∩B)′∪C? yes that means

Comment: " exactly as you wrote it. The "2" is between A and B.The C circle that has "4" is far away from other circles"  Yeah.  that makes utterly no sense whatsoever.  It's a picture of circles in space and has nothing whatsover to do with collections of numbers and which numbers are in which collections.  There is nothing meaningful that I can answer as this picture is .... nonsense.  ... to be cont.....

Comment: Sets are collections of items.  They are like bags filled with things.  We are interested in what is or is not in the bags and what items to some of the bags have in common.  We don't care *where* the bags are, or what "shape" the bags have.  In fact such questions are meaningless..... I can not help you with this question because the question makes no sense.

Comment: @fleablood Yes ,diagram Venn if it was existing it should have all circles "together" right? now we see a circle that it is far away from the other 3 . I mean the circle C is far away from the other "3 circles".If there was a venn diagram it should have combine all the circles together right? it can't be that distance as the C circle has with other 3

Comment: ......  Okay.... Did you mean to draw that $A$ has $1, 2$ (that is $A = \{1,2\}$ and $B$ has $2$ and $3$ ($B = \{2,3\}$) and that $C=\{4\}$ and that $5$ is an element not int $A,B,$ or $C$.

Comment: yes the 5 it doesn't belong to a circle it is the white space ,lol

Comment: Okay.   So you have five items..... 1,2,3,4,5.  ANd $A$ has two items: 1 and 2.  And $B$ has two items $2$ and $3$.  And $C$ has one item $4$.   .... So $A\cap B$ will be all the items $A$ and $B$ have in common (what are those).  $(A\cap B)'$ are all the other items in the universe except those they have in common (what are those).  And $(A\cap B)'\cup C$ will be all those its as well as any items in $C$.  So what are those.

Comment: You drawing should look more that you only have three circles  Circle A will have 1 and 2 in it.  Circle B will have 2 and 3 in it.  You should *not* have drawn 2 in its own separate circle.  The circle A and B should have a common "fingernail shaped" area in common.  $2$ goes into it as $2$ is an element $A$ and $B$ has in common.  But it is not in a circle by itself.

Comment: yes you are right the 2 is not a circle- it is the inside of the A and B circles that it has inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image should look more like this. The area $A$ and $B$ have in common is a shared area; not a separate circle.

[image]

Now $A \cap B$ are the things that $A = \{1,2\}$ and $B = \{2,3\}$ have in common.  They have $2$ in common so $A\cap B = \{2\}$

$(A\cap B)'$ is everything *else* that *isnt* in $A\cap B =\{2\}$. That is $1,3,4,5;$ everything except $2$.  So $(A\cap B)' = \{1,3,4,5\}$.

And $C = \{4\}$.  And $(A\cap B)' \cup C$ is every that $(A\cap B)' = \{1,3,4,5\}$ has combined with everything $C = \{4\}$ has.  That is $\{1,3,4,5\}$ combined with $\{4\}$ so that is $\{1,3,4,5\}$.

So $(A\cap B)' \cup C = \{1,3,4,5\}$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram from here as it seems it is not a venn diagramm...but it is euler diagram ..am I right?

Comment: from wikipedia venn seems to be combination....?

Comment: Excuse me very much...but the image it was truly ugly :-)...and I have changhed it.

Comment: No.  Your diagram, if anything, is more of a Venn diagram than an Euler diagram.  Venn and Euler diagrams are similar enough to be the same (what difference there is too subtle to worry about).  My complaint was your drawing wasn't at all clear.  It looked like 1,2 and 3 where *labels* of sets and not the *elements of the set and that there were three different sets and overlap between the sets 1,2, and 3.

Comment: @fleablood How can it be more a Venn diagram than an Euler diagram when it is definitely an Euler diagram and definitely not a Venn diagram?

Comment: It's definitely *not* an Euler diagram (which designates hierarchy and demonstrates areas being a entire class of things)  This diagram is *trying* (but failing to) demonstrate individual elements $1,2,3,4,5$ within geographical areas representing sets.  That's a Venn diagram.

Comment: @fleablood Hmm. As far as I understand it, a Venn diagram shows all possible ways of combining $n$ sets, whereas an Euler diagram shows some of those ways. This is supported by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_diagram): "Venn diagrams are a more restrictive form of Euler diagrams. A Venn diagram must contain all $2^n$ logically possible zones of overlap between its $n$ curves, representing all combinations of inclusion/exclusion of its constituent sets." Do you have a different definition?

Comment: (Also, I realize now that I didn't see the original at first, only your corrected version; sorry for the confusion. That being said, it's still more of an Euler diagram to me.)